# Fancybox won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Can't seem to get Fancybox to work - it just links to the 1st pic. I get the error: uncaught typeerror object # an object has no method 'fancybox'.

**HTML**

```
<a class="fancybox" data-thumbnail="http://staging.timeoutchicago.com/sites/timeoutchicago.com/files/imagecache/timeout_slideshow_player_thumbnail/P1010923.JPG" href="http://staging.timeoutchicago.com/sites/timeoutchicago.com/files/imagecache/timeout_492x330/P1010923.JPG"><img alt="" src="http://staging.timeoutchicago.com/sites/timeoutchicago.com/files/toclogo.jpg"></a>

<br />

<a class="fancybox" data-thumbnail="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"></a>​
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
            helpers: {
                thumbs: {
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    source: function(current) {
                        return $(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Header**

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
```

It does seem to be pulling in the external files according to the Source in Chrome's Developer Tools.

Thx

Comment: Can you provide a URL to this page?

Comment: Sure thing:  http://bit.ly/VAnpqb

Comment: @user6347 you are not adding the plugin in your page. the script you have add is just "Thumbnail helper for fancyBox".

Comment: I don't understand.  What are you saying should change?

Comment: @user6347 one min, I will check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm. It looks like jquery is loaded twice. Once with

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the other (harder to find)

`http://staging.timeoutchicago.com/sites/timeoutchicago.com/files/advagg_js/js_13ec2e29dba08b369ccfdde54d836ec0_8.js`

It looks like you're using drupal and with a bit of googling, it sounds like it injects a version of jquery for you (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2)

The reason that error is occuring is the conflict between the two libraries. Try following this update
http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Comment: I see, that's why I couldn't find another version.  I turned off the jquery_update module and now it says I'm using version 1.2.6.  So it seems that advagg(which is necessary) is going to create some jquery version.  Is there a way to only use the newer jquery version with Fancybox?

Comment: Ok I was able to suppress the other instance of jquery so it is now running "1.8.2".  Fancy box still won't show.

Comment: Do you have an updating link? the current one still shows 1.3 injected

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I run jQuery(".fancybox").jquery on it, it shows me 1.8.2.

Comment: can you give me an updated link to the page where you've removed one instance of jquery

Answer (score 2):

You're pulling in the two versions of jQuery.

When you execute `jQuery(".fancybox").jquery` from the console, you get `1.3.2`. Undoubtedly, this is not compatible with fancybox.

jQuery 1.8.2 is loaded via the Google CDN with your explicit `script` tag request.

jQuery 1.3.2 is loaded as part of `http://staging.timeoutchicago.com/sites/timeoutchicago.com/files/advagg_js/js_13ec2e29dba08b369ccfdde54d836ec0_8.js`, which comes from Drupal injecting this library for its own purposes.

For future reference, I was able to locate this file by using the Chrome Developer Tools, sorting by file size (largest first) and then looking at the JS files... found it pretty quickly after that.

Comment: Thx.  Which tab are you on for the Chrome tools?  I looked at Sources and don't see an option to sort.

Comment: Ok I was able to suppress the other instance of jquery so it is now running "1.8.2".  Fancy box still won't show.  It says that Fancybox is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and I resolved it by changing the double quotes in the line:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

To single quotes:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Sort of a 'gotcha' since the fancyBox site has double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

if anything does not work:

```
 parent.window.document.getElementById("fancybox-wrap").style.display = 'none';
```

This hiding fancybox.